# Nginx rewrite based on header value

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx.conf which basically looks like (unnecessary parts omitted):

```
upstream app {
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app;
    }
}
```

I want to configure nginx so that the value of a specific header is used to rewrite the url being passed to the upstream.

For example, let's assume that I have a request to `/test` with the header `Accept: application/vnd.demo.v1+json`. I'd like it to be redirected to the upstream URL `/v1/test`, i.e. basically the upstream app will receive the request `/v1/test` without the header.

Similarly, the request to `/test` and the header `Accept: application/vnd.demo.v2+json` should be redirected to the upstream URL `/v2/test`.

Is this feasible? I've looked into the [IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) nginx module, but the many warnings in there made me hesitant to use it.

Thanks,

r.

**edit**

In case there's no match, I'd like to return a `412 Precondition Failed` immediately from nginx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `Accept` header does not contain required header return error.

```
map $http_accept $version {
    default "";
    "~application/vnd\.demo\.v2\+json" "v2";
    "~application/vnd\.demo\.v1\+json" "v1";
}

server {

    location @app {
        if ($version = "") {
            return 412;
        }
        ...;
        proxy_pass http://app/$version$uri$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. You're right I didn't specify it (I've edited the original question). Is there a way to directly return a `412 Precondition Failed` in case the header does not contain any matching type?

Comment: You could set default to something else and use `if` to check variable value.

Comment: Thank you, even though I'm a little allergic to `if` statements after all the warnings that are on the official docs ^^_

Comment: > There are cases where you simply cannot avoid using an if, for example if you need to test a variable which has no equivalent directive.